# Why media queries don't work for mobile corectly?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

У меня есть следующий код

```
.bg-if-premium {
    background-image: url(photo_2021-05-22_20-40-40.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    background-position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.bg-if-free {
    background-image: url(photo_2021-04-16_16-43-00.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .bg-if-premium .bg-if-free {
        background-image: none; 
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .bg-if-premium .bg-if-free {
        background-image: none; 
    }
}
```

But on a mobile device, the background is still present. How to solve the problem?

Comment: I think you probably want a `,` between `.bg-if-premium` and `.bg-if-free` in your media queries since I'm guessing only one of those is active at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .bg-if-premium, 
  .bg-if-free {
        background-image: none; 
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .bg-if-premium, 
  .bg-if-free {
        background-image: none; 
    }
}
```

Include the @media screen and (desired width) and like Mordred stated, separate the class identifiers by a comma.

Also since it looks like your working from a website first approach, you shouldn't have to include both of these screen queries. The first one will do the trick.